# Out of memory issue while running query in table with jsonb field in Postgresql-13

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

```
**QUERY:**
 *SELECT first_table.claimno,
    first_table.claseq,
    first_table.clientname,
    first_table.linseq,
    first_table.batchdate,
    first_table.deny_proc_code,
    first_table.allow_proc_code,
    first_table.predictions,
    first_table.score,
    second_table.deleted,
    second_table.review
   FROM (( SELECT t.id,
            (t.data -> 'claimno'::text) AS claimno,
            (t.data ->> 'claseq'::text) AS claseq,
            (t.response ->> 'clientcode'::text) AS clientname,
            to_timestamp((((t.response ->> 'timestamp'::text))::numeric)::double precision) AS batchdate,
            (o.value ->> 'linseq'::text) AS linseq,
            (o.value ->> 'deny_proc_code'::text) AS deny_proc_code,
            (o.value ->> 'allow_proc_code'::text) AS allow_proc_code,
            (k.value ->> 'action'::text) AS predictions,
            ((k.value ->> 'score'::text))::numeric AS score
           FROM dummy t,
            LATERAL jsonb_array_elements((t.response -> 'lines'::text)) o(value),
            LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(
                CASE
                    WHEN (jsonb_typeof((o.value -> 'flags'::text)) ~~ 'array'::text) THEN (o.value -> 'flags'::text)
                    ELSE '[{"key": "team_q:"}]'::jsonb
                END) k(value)) first_table
     JOIN ( SELECT (k.value ->> 'deleted'::text) AS deleted,
            (k.value ->> 'review'::text) AS review,
            (k.value ->> 'claseq'::text) AS claseq,
            (t.data -> 'claimno'::text) AS claimno,
            (k.value ->> 'linseq'::text) AS linseq
           FROM dummy t,
            LATERAL jsonb_array_elements((t.data -> 'lines'::text)) o(value),
            LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(
                CASE
                    WHEN (jsonb_typeof((o.value -> 'flags'::text)) ~~ 'array'::text) THEN (o.value -> 'flags'::text)
                    ELSE '[{"key": "team_q:"}]'::jsonb
                END) k(value)) second_table ON (((first_table.claseq = second_table.claseq) AND (first_table.linseq = second_table.linseq))));*
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**
postgres=#
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed

```
$dmsg
[10881799.496693] [41883] 1983985914 41883    28630      272      59        0             0 sshd
[10881799.497029] [41892] 1983985914 41892    29461      145      16        0             0 bash
[10881799.497373] [42010]     0 42010    29173      304      63        0             0 sshd
[10881799.497698] [42237]     0 42237    54438      477      63        0             0 dzdo
[10881799.498037] [42238]     0 42238    49670      189      55        0             0 su
[10881799.498366] [42239]    26 42239    29983      145      17        0             0 bash
[10881799.498707] [42286] 1983984643 42286    28630      263      59        0             0 sshd
[10881799.499036] [42287]     0 42287    29173      305      61        0             0 sshd
[10881799.499384] [42297]    26 42297    46729      259      45        0             0 psql
[10881799.499735] [42298]    26 42298   105479     1044      83      196             0 postmaster
[10881799.500076] [42307] 1983984643 42307    28630      276      58        0             0 sshd
[10881799.500448] [42308] 1983984643 42308    29461      109      16        0             0 bash
[10881799.500796] [42319] 1983984643 42319     6061      141      18        0             0 sftp-server
[10881799.501171] [42663]     0 42663    27023       24      10        0             0 tail
[10881799.501538] [42794]     0 42794    30815      339      63        0             0 sshd
[10881799.501896] [42830]     0 42830    30815      325      61        0             0 sshd
[10881799.502277] [42831]     0 42831    29992      135      16        0             0 bash
[10881799.502656] [43249]     0 43249    29173      305      62        0             0 sshd
[10881799.503026] [43358]     0 43358    94257     4873     151        0          -900 rhsmd
[10881799.503412] [43474] 1983985914 43474    28630      297      58        0             0 sshd
[10881799.503793] [43484] 1983985914 43484    29461      129      15        0             0 bash
[10881799.504163] [43832]    89 43832    23066      299      47        0             0 cleanup
[10881799.504564] [43833]    89 43833    23030      297      48        0             0 trivial-rewrite
[10881799.504957] [43840]    89 43840    23081      273      46        0             0 smtp
[10881799.505342] [43927]     0 43927    54438      480      60        0             0 dzdo
[10881799.505716] [43934]     0 43934    49670      192      55        0             0 su
[10881799.506103] [43935]    26 43935    29983      146      16        0             0 bash
[10881799.506480] [43998]    26 43998    46729      259      44        0             0 psql
[10881799.506860] [43999]    26 43999   105475     1331      99      195             0 postmaster
[10881799.507244] [44569]    26 44569   104789      807      77      244             0 postmaster
[10881799.507616] Out of memory: Kill process 37366 (postmaster) score 474 or sacrifice child
[10881799.508019] Killed process 37366 (postmaster), UID 26, total-vm:5169780kB, anon-rss:4639752kB, file-rss:656kB, shmem-rss:133972kB
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: You are running out of memory disable memory overcommit on the operating system and look at the memory context dump in the PostgreSQL log. Examine the execution plan

Comment: -bash-4.2$ cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
2
-bash-4.2$ This is my value of overcommit_memory. The query runs individually but get stuck once joined.

Comment: I get the result when I remove row fetched and only get the count(*) in above query.

Comment: Anyway, look into the PostgreSQL log to see which process failed and why. It might also be interesting to know what extensions are installed.

Comment: I fixed the problem of view by creating some btree indexes. Thanks for the support. Now I need to add the same view on another query that is throwing an Invalid DSA memory allocation issue.